# Zorn's Lemma's chain condition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Zorn's Lemma requires that every chain in a partially ordered set $X$ has an upper bound. In [this article](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/08/12/how-to-use-zorns-lemma/) Gowers uses Zorn's Lemma to find a maximal linearly independent (over $\mathbb{Q}$) subset of $\mathbb{R}$. He does this by looking at the set of all linearly independent subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with the partial order $\subset$.

He checks that every chain has an upper bound by considering a collection $Y$ of nested linearly independent subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. He defines the upper bound as their union. Thus every chain has an upper bound and Zorn's lemma can show that a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ exists.

**But what if $Y$ is infinite?** It's not too hard to think of a chain in this case that has no upper bound- just keep adjoining appropriately chosen irrational numbers to get another subset of $\mathbb{R}$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. The chain of such subsets has no upper bound, right?

In general, when you prove that every chain in $X$ has an upper bound, you need to consider finite *and* infinite chains, right? So how come Gowers, in paragraph 24 (below), implicitly assumed that $Y$ is a finite collection? Obviously it is easy to find the upper bound of a finite chain.

> All we have to do if we want to apply Zorn’s lemma is check that every chain has an upper bound. So let us imagine that we have a collection $Y$ of linearly independent subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and that for any two of those sets one is contained in the other. What could serve as an upper bound? By definition it has to be a set that contains all the sets in $Y$, so it has to contain their union. We want it to be linearly independent, so the smaller it is, the better. So there is basically only one candidate to try: the union itself. Is the union linearly independent? Well, if $t_1,\dots,t_n$ belong to the union, then each $t_i$ belongs to some linearly independent set $L_i\in Y$. Because $Y$ is a chain, one of these sets $L_i$ contains all the others. If that is $L_j$, then the linear independence of $L_j$ implies that no non-trivial linear combination of $t_1,\dots,t_n$ can be zero, which proves that the union of the sets in $Y$ is linearly independent, just as we wanted. Therefore, by Zorn’s lemma, there is a maximal linearly independent set.

Comment: Why is the union not an upper bound when $Y$ is infinite?

Comment: Since there are no paragraph numbers, it is incredibly uncomfortable to count 24 paragraphs without mistakes. How about making your question self contained and quote this paragraph in your question?

Comment: Okay... any way to make it stick out from the rest of the text?

Comment: In the meantime, I guessed which paragraph tripped you, and I'm glad to see I was correct. But self-contained posts are an important thing anyway.

Comment: Isn't an infinite union "illegal"? If not, by analogous logic, consider the set $X$ of natural numbers partially ordered by $\leq$. Now consider the chain $1,2,3,4...$. Can't you claim the infinite sum $1+2+3+4...$ is an upper bound even though there is obviously no upper bound for this chain?

Comment: I'm new to Zorn's lemma... so that was probably not analogous logic. I guess my trouble is I don't see how an infinite union can be an upper bound for a chain. If the upper bound is infinite, doesn't that mean there is no upper bound i.e. the chain is unbounded?

Comment: @agrasin: There is nothing "illegal" by an infinite union. If $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a set, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ is also a set, as guaranteed by the axiom of union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is not that $Y$ is finite. But in order to verify that $\bigcup Y$, as the increasing union of linearly independent sets, is linearly independent, we only need to verify that finite combinations with non-zero coefficients do not produce $0$.

So given finitely many vectors (or in this case, real numbers) in $\bigcup Y$, there is some $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ that each real number lies in one of the $Y_i$'s, but since this is a finite chain, there is some $Y_k$ such that $Y_i\subseteq Y_k$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. And since $Y_k$ is linearly independent, the vectors we picked initially cannot produce $0$, so they cannot do so in $\bigcup Y$ either.

---

This is a very typical use of Zorn's lemma. We pick some property which is of finite character. So if it wouldn't hold, there would be a finite subchain whose maximal element will witness this failure.

But you are correct. We cannot just assume our chains are finite. Finite chains are ***always*** bounded, since they have a maximal element.

Comment: In the first line when you say "in order to verify that $Y$... is linearly independent" do you mean "the upper bound of $Y$"?

Comment: Err, yes, the union over $Y$.

Comment: Okay. If $Y$ is infinite, than the union will be infinite. But isn't saying the upper bound is infinite equivalent to saying there is no upper bound i.e. the chain is unbounded?

Comment: Analogously, the sequence $1,2,3...$ is bounded by $\infty$ is the same as saying the sequence is unbounded.

Comment: (1) No, infinite linear orders *could* have maximal elements; (2) the upper bound does not need to lie *within* the chain, just within the partial order.